# dplyr mutate with ifelse or case_when not working as expected?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with two columns:

```
df <- data.frame (a  = c(NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA),
                  b = c(1, 2, 5, 3, 6, 3, 2, 1, 4))

   a b
1 NA 1
2  0 2
3 NA 5
4 NA 3
5 NA 6
6 NA 3
7  0 2
8  0 1
9 NA 4
```

When the value in column a is 0, I want to replace the value in column b; desired end result is:

```
   a b
1 NA 1
2  0 0
3 NA 5
4 NA 3
5 NA 6
6 NA 3
7  0 0
8  0 0
9 NA 4
```

I tried various combinations of mutate with ifelse and case_when, and all but one replaces all of column b with column a values, 0 as well as NA.

Failed attemps:

```
df %>%
  mutate(b = case_when(a == 0 ~ 0))

df %>%
  mutate(b = case_when(a == 0 ~ 0, 
                       TRUE ~ as.numeric(as.character(a))))

df %>%
  mutate(b = ifelse(a==0, a, b))
```

All result in:

```
   a  b
1 NA NA
2  0  0
3 NA NA
4 NA NA
5 NA NA
6 NA NA
7  0  0
8  0  0
9 NA NA
```

After much consternation, I finally found a solution that produces the result I'm after:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(b = ifelse(is.na(a), b, a))

   a b
1 NA 1
2  0 0
3 NA 5
4 NA 3
5 NA 6
6 NA 3
7  0 0
8  0 0
9 NA 4
```

But I'm still perplexed as to why the others did not work as expected. Would love some insight here.

Comment: You just need `TRUE ~ b` i.e. `df %>% mutate(b = case_when(a == 0 ~ 0, TRUE ~b))`

Comment: @akrun that fixed the `case_when` version; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using %in% instead of == can be useful where there are NA values.

In base R the following will give you what you want.

```
df$b[df$a %in% 0] <- 0
```

Using this in dplyr is slightly more complicated than base R, but simpler than the previous solutions:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(b = if_else(a %in% 0, 0, b))
```

The reason for the problems is that NA == 0 gives NA, not FALSE.  NA %in% 0 gives FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(b = if_else(a == 0 & !is.na(a), 0, b)) 

#>    a b
#> 1 NA 1
#> 2  0 0
#> 3 NA 5
#> 4 NA 3
#> 5 NA 6
#> 6 NA 3
#> 7  0 0
#> 8  0 0
#> 9 NA 4
```

Comment: this works--but I'm curious why `mutate(b = ifelse(is.na(a), b, a))` works while `mutate(b = ifelse(a==0, a, b))` does not. Leading with `a==0` requires `& !is.na(a)`, while leading with `is.na(a)` doesn't. Is R interpreting the NA values in column a as "0" in `ifelse(a==0, a, b))` ?

Comment: The reason, I guess, is because `ifelse(NA == 0, 1, 0)` produces `NA`, @jdunc923.

Answer (score 0):

In general any operation on an `NA` becomes an `NA`, so when comparing vectors that have `NA` the results will be `NA` where either of the original items was `NA`.

If you're willing to eschew `dplyr` you can do this in base R:

```
df$b <- ifelse(
          is.na(df$a), 
          df$b, 
          ifelse(
            df$a == 0, 
            0,  
            df$b
          )
        )
```

Comment: this makes sense, but I'd thought that with the `case_when` or `ifelse` the code should ignore anything that doesn't match that statement--so "if a=0, replace b with a; otherwise, keep b". It's like it ignores the if a=0 bit and just replaces all b with a. However, "if a is NA, keep b, otherwise replace b with a" does work, which i find curious.

Comment: Not sure this addresses your point, but understand that if there's an `NA` involved the `ifelse()` evaluates nothing more and simply returns `NA`. For example, `ifelse(TRUE, 1, 0)` returns 1 but `ifelse(NA, 1, 0)` returns `NA`.

Comment: ah that's interesting. I'm not sure I've ever worked with a column with this many NAs so I've never come across the issue before.